# Is there a way to avoid triggering an alarm?

Tags: gtfo

Doors leading to different numbered areas sometimes indicate that opening them will trigger an alarm. This alarm will draw an unending number of enemies towards the players, until the players have spent enough time in specific positions.

So far, when playing with just one other player, this has always resulted in our death. A single "[big striker](https://gtfo.gamepedia.com/Big_Striker)", together with around 8 "regular" enemies is too much for two players to deal with.

Therefore, is there a away to avoid triggering the alarm? It seems baffling to me that a game that reminds you at every opportunity to remain stealthy or else you would die would force you to not be stealthy anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Alarms are mandatory and the only non-stealth section of the game, where guns can be used at any time.

Scans do take less time with more people, though, so if you're struggling, try having both players there.

Comment: The problem is that the points where the game desires me to stand are usually not in cover, and standing in the open with a ton of enemies shooting and clawing at you is not a good way to preserve health.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably the biggest flaw with the game's design, but unless you have substantial numbers of items to make it easier, it's always gonna be a challenge.

Comment: From my experience, an alarm is necessary to proceed after only three rooms explored. If you are lucky, you find some ammo and health until then. And even that doesn't really help that much, if you are only two players.

Comment: Therein lies the problem.